# How to render xlsx inside iFrame in reactjs?

Tags: html, reactjs, file, iframe, xlsx

Can we render xlsx file in html ?

Should be compatible with the browsers like IE and chrome.

```
<iframe
 height="500px"
 width="100%"
 src={file.url}
/>
```

But after the page is loaded this actually downloads the files.

Comment: You will need some JS plugin that can read excel and output Json array. Or you may upload excel to your server, and let server convert the file into Json and send it back to browser. Add more details to your question so people know which of these solutions you seek.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it using this API :

`https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/Example.xlsx`

Insert this inside an Iframe you will be able to see excel.

Answer (score 1):

**Excel or .xlsx extension files do not display natively in a browser/iframes.**

The closest you could get is to have a library that reads the Excel file and then generates HTML based on its content.

Or

Another solution would be to convert the file to pdf and display it in the iframe.